# How to use forEach() method in Java 8 loop n+1 time but my list size is random like n, n-1, n-2

Tags: java, java-stream

How to use forEach() method in Java 8 loop `n` time but my list size is always random like `n-1, n-2, etc...`. If list size is less then n number then rest value would be zero/empty of each object value.

Below example I have Data3 object which have ID, year, `listOfCompanies` and value as per below code  in the end I have list of Data3 object which I want to loop using for each java8 but I want to loop 8 times for list of companies if no value then put Empty value for each object.

I try using `IntStream.range` function but its not working for me.

```
@lombok.Data
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Data3{
    int id;
    int year;
    List<String> listOfCompanies;
    double value;
}

List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("TCS"); list1.add("Cognizant");list1.add("Wipro");list1.add("Zensar");
list1.add("IBM");list1.add("Amdocs");
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add("TCS");list2.add("Cognizant");list2.add("Wipro");
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
list3.add("TCS");list3.add("Cognizant");list3.add("Wipro");list3.add("Zensar");
list3.add("IBM");
List<String> list4 = new ArrayList<>();
list4.add("TCS");list4.add("Cognizant");
Data3 d1 = new Data3(1, 1990, list1, 10);
Data3 d2 = new Data3(2, 1991, list2, 20);
Data3 d3 = new Data3(3, 1992, list3, 30);
Data3 d4 = new Data3(4, 1993, list4, 40);

List<Data3> listOfDataValues = new ArrayList<>();
listOfDataValues.add(d1);
listOfDataValues.add(d2);
listOfDataValues.add(d3);
listOfDataValues.add(d4);


listOfDataValues.stream().map(value -> new Data3(value.getId(), value.getYear(), IntStream.range(1, 8).mapToObj(index -> value.getListOfCompanies().get(index).isEmpty() ? "" : value.getListOfCompanies().get(index)), value.getValue()));
```

> Expected OP: (result required to loop 8 times list of companies if no
> value then put Empty value )

```
[Test.Data3(id=1, year=1990, listOfCompanies=[TCS, Cognizant, Wipro, Zensar, IBM, Amdocs,"",""], value=10.0), 
Test.Data3(id=2, year=1991, listOfCompanies=[TCS, Cognizant, Wipro,"","","","",""], value=20.0), 
Test.Data3(id=3, year=1992, listOfCompanies=[TCS, Cognizant, Wipro, Zensar, IBM,"","",""], value=30.0),` 
Test.Data3(id=4, year=1993, listOfCompanies=[TCS, Cognizant,"","","","","",""], value=40.0)]
```

Comment: You're creating 8 identical new `Data3` instances for each `Data3` instance you are starting with. You are not doing any processing involving the `listOfCompanies`.

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks for suggestion, update to my new code, tried with new code but still not working, any hint?

Comment: What happens when you call `value.getListOfCompanies().get(index).isEmpty()` when index is larger than `value.getListOfCompanies().size()`? Can you think of another condition you could use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listOfDataValues.stream().forEach(value -> {
    return IntStream.range(1, 8).mapToObj(new Data3(value.getId(), value.getYear(), value.getListOfCompanies(), value.getValue()));
});
```

The code snippet is wrong for:

1.in forEach you don't need to return anything

2.mapToObj needs IntFunction, so you need to take an Integer as input

Actually you need to complement "" according to the size of listOfCompanies, so getting the quantity to be complemented is the key:

```
listOfDataValues.stream().forEach(value -> {
            int size = value.getListOfCompanies().size();
            IntStream.range(0, 8 - size).forEach(index->value.getListOfCompanies().add(""));
        });
```

Comment: What if I want to add all these new values ​​to a new list? And keep the old one as before.

Comment: I don't think it's feasible, listOfCompanies is the only list in Data3, either old or new, you can't have both

Comment: It's ok, u r welcome

Comment: You don’t need `stream()` if all you’re doing is `forEach`. The inner operation is even more an unnecessary use of a Stream operation. Just use `listOfDataValues.forEach(value -> { List<String> l = value.getListOfCompanies(); l.addAll(Collections.nCopies(8 - l.size(), "")); });` or, if it really has to be a Stream operation, `listOfDataValues.stream().map(Data3::getListOfCompanies).forEach(l -> l.addAll(Collections.nCopies(8 - l.size(), "")));`

Comment: Thx @Holger, now I know nCopies

Comment: Yes, @Holger, what if i have list of object instead of list of string containing id and company_name and i have to loop 8 times for each with next increment id. what changes required or which would be worked for me?

Comment: For example like : List<Companies> listOfCompanies = new ArraysList<>();
        listOfCompanies.add(new Companies(1, "TCS"));
        listOfCompanies.add(new Companies(2, "Cognizant"));
        listOfCompanies.add(new Companies(3, "Wipro"));